# Not closing a form with AxAcroPdf reader

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a winform with a pdf reader control the AxAcroPdf reader, the thing is after I retreive the pdf document to the contorl, when I want to close the form, it takes about 30 seconds to acomplish the event, I have been searching for the couse, event put the Dispose() event to the control, but cant make to close the form in the apropiate time, always takes about 30 seconds to close the form...

Here is the code in the form where I have the control...

```
Private Sub cargarPdf(ByRef nombre_Archivo)
        Try
            AxAcroPDF1.Visible = True
            Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(cadena)
            Dim comando As SqlCommand = con.CreateCommand()
            comando.CommandText = "SELECT file_stream FROM dbo.Tabla_archivos where name = @name"
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nombre_Archivo)
            con.Open()
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = comando.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            dr.Read()
            Dim bufferSize As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetBytes(0, 0, Nothing, 0, 0))
            datos = New Byte(bufferSize - 1) {}
            dr.GetBytes(0, 0, datos, 0, bufferSize)
            dr.Close()
            WriteBinaryFile("C:\Cobit\" + nombre_Archivo, datos)
            AxAcroPDF1.src = "C:\Cobit\" + nombre_Archivo
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

And here is the code in the base form...

```
Private Sub BtnCerrar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If NombreLbl.Text = "Vista Archivos de evidencia" Then
            Try
                Frm_vista_archivos_evidencia.AxAcroPDF1.Dispose()

            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

The form that has the control is a derived form from Frm_base

Comment: I had this issue once, the only thing that worked for me in the end was setting the reader's source to a non-existent document just before closing it, that seems to free everything up and allow the reader to close

Answer (score 1):

There has been a bug in recent versions of Acrobat Reader that causes a delay when the control is disposed on Form closure.  There appears to be some link to it having a PDF document open.  You can force the control to close the document by setting its `src` property to an nonexistent PDF file; setting it to Nothing or empty string has no effect.  Credit for this document closure technique goes to "kenstanley2014" in the Adobe forum posting [How do I clear the file from AxAcroPDF object?](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/442298).  If you first close the file and then the form, it will close quickly.  However, I found this has to be via two separate UI interactions as putting them in the same method fails as does setting the `src` property and using a timer to trigger the close command.

For whatever reason, I decided to see if hiding the form would have an effect.  It does!, and there is no need to set the `src` property at all.  Just set the Form's `Visible` property to False in the FormClosed event handler.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    Me.Visible = False
End Sub
```

I have no idea why this works and your experience may be different.
Tested on Windows 10 64-bit with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, ver. 15.023.20056.16516.

Comment: Thankyou I will try these way, and when I get to office will check the version and posit here what happens for documentation porpoises... Thankyou TnTinMn

Comment: Hi @TnTinMn, I already tried by putting the visible property to false, but did not work because I am using a sub for showing the forms in the application... form_1.showdialog(me) and in the next line form_1.dispose(), so does not work in the closing event and in the closed event eather. But I had on code the remove control in the form, and It work fine, I check several times and didnt crash at all. The version of acrobat is 2015.023.20056; os is windows 10 64 bits. thenks in advanced for taking the time to read these lines...

Comment: @JorgeTorselli, how you show the form containing the AxAcroPDF control should not matter.  The FormClosed event will fire.  In reality, I only show the use of form events because that is what most people use; I prefer to override the method that raises the event: `Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosed(e As FormClosedEventArgs)`.

Comment: I just found out what was causing the exception when I closed the form, because of what I wrote before by using the sub, and yes you where right, I was making the mistake off using another event, but the thing is that when I try to use the solution that worked on youre machine, in the form closed event, in my machine it took 19 to 25 second to close the form... The only way that has been fast is to remove the control...

Comment: Even I tried to use Overriding the event as you comented but still the same 19 to 25 seconds to close the form... :( is there another control that can read PDF files, to avoid using adobe reader...?

Comment: @JorgeTorselli, I just updated my system to the newest version of Adobe Reader DC and it appears that this glitch has been resolved.  The new version is 2015.023.20070.  Hopefully it will work for you as well.